# Ошибка в заведомо правильном SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

При попытке выполнить данную строку, MySQL ругается на слово VISIBLE:

`` CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `field_UNIQUE` ON `db1`.`table1` (`name` ASC) VISIBLE; ``

Сама ошибка:

`[1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE' at line 1`

Код верный, так как работал на другой машине, возможно в другой конфигурации. Доступа к машине нету, так что узнать, в конфиге ли проблема не получится.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393245/mysql-error-1064-syntax-but-everything-seems-fine

Comment: какая у вас версия, VISIBLE/INVISIBLE добавили в 8.0?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Это кусок кода интерпрайса, нельзя мне трогать этот файлик)

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Вы были правы, все из-за версии...